# Some animations not exporting with FBX

Tags: animation

I’m having an issue where some of my animations are not exporting with my model/armature. I designed everything in Blender and I’m trying to export as FBX to import into Unity. For my main character I designed 19 animations. But for some reason, when I export as FBX, 6 of those animations disappear. The file is too big to upload here but I would gladly send via email (briankenny718@yahoo.com). Any help would be so greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to watch the first 8 minutes to know [how the action editor and the NLA work](https://youtu.be/84ALxrtBkps?t=1013).

In general the clips you are not seeing, are in "replace" mode or have not been stored correctly on the *Action Editor* with it´s corresponding user (but as a fake user), are not present on the graph editor and are not taken in account.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response, I'll look into this and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hi all, here you can download the file: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51570

Comment: Yes, those missing animations had to be added in the NLA editor, by selecting the animation in the Action Editor, then clicking the button with the two down arrows in the NLA editor. Thanks so much for leading me to this discovery, I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Linking to your video that is 30 minutes long and spends 5 minutes begging people to subscribe doesn't answer this question.

Comment: I guess you don't know what "first 8 minutes" mean? Whatever...

Answer (score 6):

If anyone is coming across this problem still having issues, this blender ticket provided the answer for me. https://developer.blender.org/T54548

I had a number of different actions from my blender file not exporting. Those that did not export had what Philipp who answered the ticket refers to as "invalid paths". With the problem action selected in the action editor, I could see these invalid paths highlighted in red. Screenshotted is me mid-deletion clearing them out. Once the invalid paths were removed the action showed up in the output fbx file and I did not have to "push down" actions into the NLA editor.

[image]