# Why does exporting to FBX only include one NLA track?

Tags: export, .fbx, nla-editor

[image]

I have an armature with a bunch of NLA tracks/actions on it that I would like to export to FBX. However, when I try to do so the animations in the resulting FBX are all copies of whichever NLA track was selected at the time of exporting. Meaning I get the same animation ~16 times, with varying start and end frames. The export settings are shown below. How can I get Blender to actually add all individual NLA tracks/actions to the FBX?

[It looks like the actions are stored correctly and contain no invalid paths](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/136935/some-animations-not-exporting-with-fbx), but maybe I'm missing something.

This is on Blender 2.92.

[image: FBX Export Settings]

Comment: Apparently the exporter does not unstar the starred track before baking, hence the starred track overrides every action it tries to bake. It works if you unstar the track before exporting though doesn't it?

Comment: That was the problem, thank you so much! If you post this as an answer I'll mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FBX exporter does not appear to unstar starred track for you, so any starred track will remain starred while it bakes animations ie. all the animations will look like the starred track.

To avoid this, unstar any starred track before you export.